# GPUImage ChromaKeyFilter is keying out my entire image

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, gpuimage

Just got my hand on this GPUImage framework everyone seems to be talking about..

Anyway, I'm trying to do a filter chain - the first two filters produce the expected result when chained together, but when I add the third, the entire image gets set to 0 alpha

My Code:

```
-(UIImage*)doFilter:(int)aVal{

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self];
GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter *lumFilterOne = [[GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter alloc] init];
lumFilterOne.threshold = (float)aVal/255;

GPUImageFalseColorFilter *colorAFilter = [[GPUImageFalseColorFilter alloc] init];
colorAFilter.firstColor = (GPUVector4){0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
colorAFilter.secondColor = (GPUVector4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

GPUImageChromaKeyFilter *chromaFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyFilter alloc] init];
[chromaFilter setColorToReplaceRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f];
chromaFilter.thresholdSensitivity = 0.0f;


[stillImageSource addTarget:lumFilterOne];
[stillImageSource processImage];

[lumFilterOne addTarget:colorAFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];

[colorAFilter addTarget:chromaFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];




return [chromaFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
}
```

As I said above, when I replace this

```
[colorAFilter addTarget:chromaFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];




return [chromaFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

with this (removing the chroma key filter)

```
return [colorAFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

I get the expected result - the input image thresholded to the selected threshold, and the resulting black area changed to gray, with the white remaining white.

As soon as I introduce the ChromaKey filter, the entire image is keyed out.

I am expecting to key the white out only.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this with a non-0 sensitivity? That might be triggering some odd behavior in the shader. It is a fairly new filter, so I haven't had the time to fully test it out yet. It seems to work well using the default parameters using green as a target color.

Comment: Yeah, I did try 0.4 and 1.0 sensitivity but to avail. Also, I've solved this problem by writing my own shader that performs all the steps I need at once using a lookup table. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured this out, but I'm answering my own question as I ended up just writing my own shader that does everything I need. Cheers.